# Is it possible to use a WFS layer as input on the QGIS Model Designer?

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-modeler

I've recently learned that I can get open data on QGIS by using WFS services.

[image]

Well, as it is these WFS services are very useful since the data is already in a vectorized way. However, I'd like to create an automation using the Graphical Modeler that will start a flow using a WFS layer as input. In my specific case, I've access to a WFS service that updates regularly. So, for me, it's useful automating the process of getting this data from there from time to time.

However, I didn't find anything related to WFS services in the inputs inside the Graphical Modeler:

[image]

I know I can manually add WFS layers on QGIS and then use them as vector layer inputs on the Graphical Modeler. But I was expecting to use WFS layers directly on the Graphical Modeler, just so I can transform it into a Python script that will run automatically from time to time. Is it possible to add WFS layers as input on the Graphical Modeler? If not, is there any workaround for this issue?